# How to print child fields from embedded view in a webform

Tags: views, webforms, files

I've got an embedded view (articles) in a webform with two child fields (article_title, article_body). I need to print/generate a PDF of the webform submission. The default template works, but looks messy in a table.

What is the right syntax to call the data from the child terms?

Here's my webform structure:

[image: Here's my webform structure:]

Using `print ('<b>Report Name:</b> '.$renderable['report_name']['#value']);` I can get the Report Name, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the the article_title and article_body fields. I'm not very familiar with coding and have been searching online for ages with no luck, except for [this article](http://bigsnowball.com/content/output-drupal-webform-pdf) which I can't seem to get working for my system either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try `print_r($renderable)` to see the structure of the data you're working with.

Comment: Below is one of the fields (article_title). But I still don't get what I should be using as it's key? Has it got anything to do with the fact that they're hidden in the form? But when using the default submission template, they come out fine.

[4] => Array ( [nid]
=> 231 [cid] => 4 [pid] => 2 [form_key] => article_title [name] => Title [type] => hidden [value]
=> [node_title] [extra] => Array ( [hidden_type] => value [conditional_operator] => = [private]
=> 0 [conditional_component] => [conditional_values] => ) [mandatory] => 0 [weight] => 3
[page_num] => 1 )

Comment: Guessing this is the actual submission that has gone through:

[#submission] => stdClass Object ( [sid] => 36 [nid] => 231
[submitted] => 1406779575 [remote_addr] => ::1 [uid] => 1 [name] => admin [is_draft] => 0
[data] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [value] => Array ( [0] => Milan 2 ) ) [2] => Array ( [value] =>
Array ( [0] => a:2:{i:212;a:3:{s:13:"article_title";s:38:"Takaful Ikhlas targets US$62.5
million";s:12:"article_body";s:668:"
Takaful Ikhlas anticipates 50%...

Comment: Yeah, maybe. It's hard for me to know, from this distance. You will find that using your browser's "View Source" feature will give you nicer formatting to read. ..

Comment: I think it's creating an array, which I don't know much about. I get the value of the textfield. And if I use the same code for the parent field '(print $renderable['articles']['#value']);' it just returns the word: Array. And when using the code for a child field it comes out empty and I get an error: _Notice: Undefined index: article_title_ Thanx for your help though @RimuAtkinson

Comment: Yes, it just says 'Array' because you are trying to print an array, which is impossible. You can only print individual elements of an array. Have a read of http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp :)

Comment: Thanks, been reading through a ton of articles about arrays and have a better understanding of them now, but I still can't get the right values out of my form to print. Don't know if it's because it's nested form fields or what else it could be. I've got the source code of the page with nice formatting, but still not figuring it out. Could I email it to you by any chance? See if you could make any sense of it. Sorry to ask, but I'm kinda desperate here. Let me know @RimuAtkinson